# Mapping the response to a variable angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I am using HttpClient to call a get request that returns the response in the following format.

```
{
    "organizations": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Team Red",
            "address": null,
            "sites": [
                {
                    "organization": 1,
                    "name": "Site A",
                    "address": null,
                    "lat": null,
                    "lon": null,
                    "id": 1,
                    "createdAt": "2017-10-23T11:07:11.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2017-10-23T11:07:11.000Z"
                },
                {
                    "organization": 1,
                    "name": "Site B",
                    "address": null,
                    "lat": null,
                    "lon": null,
                    "id": 2,
                    "createdAt": "2017-10-23T11:07:11.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2017-10-23T11:07:11.000Z"
                },
                {
                    "organization": 1,
                    "name": "Site C",
                    "address": null,
                    "lat": null,
                    "lon": null,
                    "id": 3,
                    "createdAt": "2017-10-23T11:07:11.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2017-10-23T11:07:11.000Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Team Blue",
            "address": null,
            "sites": [
                {
                    "organization": 2,
                    "name": "Site X",
                    "address": null,
                    "lat": null,
                    "lon": null,
                    "id": 4,
                    "createdAt": "2017-10-23T11:07:11.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2017-10-23T11:07:11.000Z"
                },
                {
                    "organization": 2,
                    "name": "Site Y",
                    "address": null,
                    "lat": null,
                    "lon": null,
                    "id": 5,
                    "createdAt": "2017-10-23T11:07:11.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2017-10-23T11:07:11.000Z"
                },
                {
                    "organization": 2,
                    "name": "Site Z",
                    "address": null,
                    "lat": null,
                    "lon": null,
                    "id": 6,
                    "createdAt": "2017-10-23T11:07:11.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2017-10-23T11:07:11.000Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to directly map the response to a organisation variable. I have attached the Service File code, as well as organisation and site file. 
The error I am getting is on response.json() and I have search that this function is not available. Any help will be appreciated.

```ts
import {Site} from "./Site";

export class Organization {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  address: string;
  sites: Site[];

  constructor(values: Object = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, values);
  }
}


---------


export class Site {
  organization: number;
  name: string;
  address: string;
  lat: string;
  lon: number;
  id: number;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: number;
}

---- API Service ----

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Organization} from "../models/Organization";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';


const API_URL = "http://localhost:1337/api";

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  public getOrganizationWithSites(): Observable<Organization[]> {

const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set("Authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MTEsIm5hbWUiOiJBdGlmIiwiaWF0IjoxNTIwMjY2NDQwLCJleHAiOjE1MjAzNTI4NDB9.GW5P7zDow4PcI9RaB3pn6KxPn929pmzPCnce6n8OCo8");
let organizations: any;
var options = {
  headers: headers
};

return this.http
      .get<Organization[]>(API_URL + '/user/organizations', options);

  }

      // private handleError(error: Response | any) {
      //   console.error('ApiService::handleError', error);
      //   return Observable.throw(error);
      // }
}



// Components Code

ngOnInit() {

    this.apiService
      .getOrganizationWithSites()
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.organizations = data;

      });
    console.log(this.organizations);
}
```

Comment: the new HttpClient class does not require the parse the response to json that why, the response that you are getting is the one you need

Comment: @Ricardo I have updated the method of APIService, as well as added the oginit() method. Its printing updefined. Please check

Comment: In the documentation (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) I check and it seem your are missing the value that you want to observe and the response type

Comment: @Ricardo, can you help me out with it point the mistake I have made. As I am new to Angular

Comment: check out also this url https://angular.io/guide/http, I m going to try to create a example for you , another thing: the subscribe method receive like the second parameter a function that receive the errors, pass a second function and try to see if the error is coming from the backend

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out. I will be waiting for your example. I have logged the error the backend is returning the same format that I have mentioned.

Comment: Console log inside your subscribe block.

Comment: Yeah I did there, and its printing the results there. But not storing in the organizations variable.

Comment: It is. But you're having a race condition. Try this outside the subscribe block.         setTimeout(()=>{
            console.log(this.organizations)
        }, 2000);  You have to do the work in the subscribe block.

Comment: I have printed out the result by calling a function on button click and its printing the values now. :)

Comment: By the way, the variable will be of Organization type. How can loop through it?

Answer (score 1):

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

The HttpClient API was introduced in the version 4.3.0. It is an evolution of the existing HTTP API and has it's own package @angular/common/http. One of the most notable changes is that now the response object is a JSON by default, so there's no need to parse it with map method anymore .Straight away we can use like below

```
return http.get(API_URL + '/user/organizations', options);
```

Then in your component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './MyComponent.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent{

    public organizations : Organization[] = [];

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {
        this.apiService
           .getOrganizationWithSites()
           .subscribe((data) => {
             this.organizations = data;
             console.log(this.organizations);


            });
        }
}
```

Comment: this.organizations refers to what? as In my case no variable is there, I need to return the observable to the component who will call that method.

Comment: @AtifJaved Then your service will only return the observable "return http.get(API_URL + '/user/organizations', options); ". And the Component that is making the call will subscribe to the call and use the result.

Answer (score 1):

remove `json` part from `response.json();` in ApiService  as per HttpClient angular 5 no need to do it. `HttpClient` implicity do it.

For More Info [Angular 5](https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced)

Comment: I have updated the method of APIService, as well as added the oginit() method. Its printing updefined. Please check